# one or multiple questions

Tags: discussion

I have a little place where my plants are, but there are a bunch of conditions that I would like to improve. I would like posting all the situation in one single question and explaining each issue. Is this correct? or should I post a question for each single issue?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for posting this question here. It can help a lot of people learn the best way to use the site! Can you give us a few more details? By conditions, do you mean things like amounts of sun, shade, water, etc. for all the plants in that one spot? That can often be one question.  If you have problems with different plants and you want to know what's wrong with each one, sometimes that's better as separate questions.  If you don't get a good answer here, feel free to post your question and someone will tell you if it should be split. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, thanks I realized that separate questions is he best option, becasue I have problems in different plants. And I found that I am not going to be able to select the best answer due to one answer can have important information about a specific plant but not of all them. Cheers!

Comment: Sounds good! Also, as you know, you can get more reputation  and privileges by asking separate questions, as long as they're not duplicates of each other. Thanks for the good answers you've already written. I look forward to your questions. Cheers back!

Comment: Never use a vague title as you did here.  You need to put info in the title that states your question, with key words or you will not get a good response.  That is true here or on any forum or similar site. As I see Stack Exchange though, it's not a discussion site, and perhaps you should go elsewhere and get more discussion (often with lots of errata and nonsense you need to filter through, but I still use them).  Then when you have a more detailed question ask it here - i.e. "What is the best way to provide adequate drainage for a container-grown pepper plant?"  But I am discussing...